# Running Libgdx Eclipse apps in iOS Simulator via RoboVM

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I can't seem to get RoboVM to run apps in the iOS Simulator via Eclipse.

I have followed [this guide](http://www.robovm.org/docs.html#eclipse), but get this error:

[image: Internal Error launching IOSDemo(1)]

when I try to do a Run as..../iOS Simulator App (iPhone or iPad). I have also tried some of the LibGDX example applications and get the same message. I can't see any other error messages in the console.

I have tried cleaning the project and recreated it several times from scratch. I have also deleted `~/.robovm/cache` to force a rebuild.

I have the following installed on my Mac Mini running OSX Lion:

- Eclipse 4.2 Kelper (64 bit)
- JDK 7 U40
- RoboVM Eclipse plugin v0.0.5
- XCode 4.3
- A wildcard development provisioning profile

Comment: Xcode 4.3 is really old. I guess you mean Xcode 4.6.3 or Xcode 5? Please open a Terminal and run "xcode-select --print-path". Does it point to the location where Xcode is installed? If not run "sudo xcode-select --switch <path-to-xcode>" to point it at the right folder.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am now up and running. Sorry for the wrong information, I am running Xcode 4.6.3. For any others that may have the same issue, I had moved xcode.app from the default /Applications folder. `xcode-select --print-path` revealed "No Xcode is selected". I set it via `sudo xcode-select --switch` as @ntherning suggested, then I got a "dyld: Library not loaded" after compile. I then moved xcode.app to /Applications and did a `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications` and bingo, all working fine.

Comment: In the next version of RoboVM you will get a nice error message when doesn't xcode-select point to a proper Xcode install. The dyld error you got was probably when you launched on the Simulator. This didn't work when Xcode was installed in a non-standard path. This will also be fixed in the next version.

Comment: Everything seems fine on my setup. But selecting run as iOS Simulator is not doing anything. Not even an error. Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: Can the IOS emulator even handle a JLWGL  application running inside RoboVM? I'd hazard a guess that the answer is no.