# Libgdx export as ios application

Tags: ios, export, libgdx

I made a game like doodle jump in libgdx, I exported as desktop and android application, but how can I export as iOS application?
Is there a way to export this as ipa?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387012/running-libgdx-eclipse-apps-in-ios-simulator-via-robovm

Comment: probably this may help. But you need to add more details in your questions. Like what effort you made and where you got stuck etc. As there can me many possible solution to this particular question

Comment: I don't have extra detalis.. I need to export my app as iOs application..

Answer (score 2):

visit 
[Robovm](http://www.robovm.com/docs#start) you need java 7 enviorment (**not compiler JRE**)
Mac

P.S. if you dont have a robovm project yet. its better to create a new project from GDXsetupUI
and paste your code there

Than also as per the IOS requirement you need to have registered Device , Developer License and Provising Certificates

Comment: So if I have no iPhone, and using windows, i can't make iPhone apps with libgdx?

Comment: Correct, you need a Mac/OSX to build native iOS applications.